# How is the Mean Value Theorem used when dealing with second derivative in this question?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and twice differentiable on $(a,b)$.  The line segment joining points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ meets $f$ at $c$,which lies between $a$ and $b$.  Prove there is a $d$ between $a$ and $b$ s.t. $f''(d)=0$.

Comment: $f'$ takes the value of the slope of the line segment in two places. One strictly between $a$ and $d$ and the other strictly between $d$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $g$ to be the affine function coinciding with $f$ at $a$ and $b$:
$$
g(x) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+f(a)
$$
and set $h\stackrel{\rm def}{=}f-g$. Since by construction and assumption $f(a)=g(a)$, $f(b)=g(b)$ and $f(c)=g(c)$, you have $h(a)=h(c)=h(b)=0$ **and** $h$ is twice differentiable. By Rolle's theorem, there exist $x,y$ in (resp.) $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ such that $h^\prime(x)=h^\prime(y)=0$.

Thus, again by Rolle's theorem (applied this time to $h^\prime$, which is continuous on $[x,y]$ and differentiable on $(x,y)$), there exists $d\in (x,y)\subset[a,b]$ such that $h^{\prime\prime}(d)=0$.

But $g$ is affine, so $g^{\prime\prime} = 0$ and therefore $h^{\prime\prime}=f^{\prime\prime}$. Hence $f^{\prime\prime}(d)=0$.